# How to filter using regex in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to filter my list by using regex.

When I type `ab*r`  into the input field it should display only this name `**abc pqr**` but it does not display the filter list why ?

[Here is my PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/e5zpSGWPZKPkSrpfSakr?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='cntrl'>
    <input type="text" ng-model='username'>
    <div ng-repeat='d in data | myfilter: username '>
      {{d.name}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using a filter like this will just not work in the way you want it to work...

Comment: can you share the code of myfilter?

Comment: I am using filter please check http://plnkr.co/edit/e5zpSGWPZKPkSrpfSakr?p=preview

Comment: sorry by mistake i didnot share code

Comment: You want to filter by a regular expression that you type in the input field? You you want all words that begin with ab and end with r, the regular expression is 'ab.*r'

Comment: I want if user type ab*r in input field it display the **abc pqr** item ..because it seach in array all items which start from "ab"  and after some charaters then have r

Comment: r may be in end or some where else ,..but first ab will come and followed by characters and then  r

Comment: did you get my point ? ab may be in first letters but there is some letters between ab and r

Comment: `ab*r` matches `abbbbbr`, etc., and even `ar`. `ab.*r` will match strings like `abc ddfgg r`. And `abc pqr`, too

Comment: ab*r matches abbbbbr is fine..can wwe filter this list if I write ab*r.display only one item **abc pqr**

Comment: Use anchors: `^ab.*r$`. See [this updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GUBnmaM1QMSBobyxtLGn?p=preview)

Comment: Check [this site](https://regex101.com/r/rW0wS5/2). You can test different regexs with your examples.

Comment: Note that your items do not have `abc pqr` entry. Is this question still relevant? If [the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870103/why-filter-not-working-using-custom-filter-in-angular-js) was posted because you found a solution for this one, please remove this question.